# Problems with Navigation (Bottom Navigation Bar)

Tags: flutter, navigation

I have persistent bottom navigation bar across my whole app (except login page). It looks like:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: IndexedStack(
      index: _currentIndex,
      children: <Widget>[
        Navigator(
            key:_userScreen,
            onGenerateRoute: (route) => MaterialPageRoute(
              settings: route,
              builder: (context) => UserPage(userId: 
                       widget.userId),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Navigator(
          key: _searchScreen,
          onGenerateRoute: (route) => MaterialPageRoute(
            settings: route,
            builder: (context) => SearchPage(userId: 
            widget.userId),
          ),
        ),
        Navigator(
          key:_optionsScreen,
          onGenerateRoute: (route) => MaterialPageRoute(
            settings: route,
            builder: (context) => OptionsPage(userId: 
            widget.userId),
          ),
        ),
      ]
  ),
   bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    selectedFontSize: 12.0,
    unselectedFontSize: 12.0,
    currentIndex: _currentIndex,
    onTap: (val) => _onTap(val, context),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue[50],
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(LineIcons.graduation_cap),
        title: Text('Courses'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(LineIcons.search),
        title: Text('Search'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(LineIcons.user),
        title: Text('Options'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

And now I want to remove bottom navigation bar on one of my pages (for opening a videoplayer). How can I do it? 
I tried to make separate route to videoPage in main of my app and go there using Navigator.pushNamed but because I am situated inside another Navigator I go to root page of that Navigator....